# How to validate whether a username is unique using joi?

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, hapi.js, joi

I read an article somewhere in which the author used [Joi](https://github.com/hapijs/joi) to validate asynchronously, whether the username is unique or not by checking with the database. I can't find it now and I want to know how can we do that with `Joi`.

Comment: I'd be interested to see what you've tried so far. I'd argue this isn't really Joi's intended use as a schema validator though. What you're describing is presumably a second level of validation once Joi has confirmed the request is valid that you'll need to implement yourself.

Comment: I had no luck finding how to do that. I guess you are right. I should use Joi only for schema validation and do async checks on some next level. It still beats me that I cant find that article.

Comment: This is what `pre` handlers are useful for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @Ankh already mentioned in the comments, I also think that checking the database isn't `joi`'s area of responsibility.

However with `joi@v16` and `any().external()` you can now do an external async validation. This can be used to do a database lookup. (Details in [release document v16](https://github.com/sideway/joi/issues/2037))

```js
const lookup = async (id) => {

    const user = await db.get('user', id);
    if (!user) {
        throw new Error('Invalid user id');
    }
};

const schema = Joi.string().external(lookup);
await schema.validateAsync('1234abcd');
```